# ProtoBuffer Length delimited field, use Fixed Length 32 bit int as length indicator

Tags: arrays, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am trying to write a a protobuffer message, and would like to know if it is possible to use a Fixed32Int instead of VarInt to indicate the length of the string that I want to write to the buffer.

I have tried, but failed, and I can't find any information on it, so wondering if anyone else has tried that.

Comment: Which language/platform (java, .net, python, etc) and library (if not the google implementation - there are others) are you using?

Comment: I tried composing the byte array myself, and deserialize it with your library protobuf-net. I have settled on using a varint instead of a fixed size 32bit int.

Comment: hmmm; `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` with one of the `PrefixStyle` options should have worked fine for fixed width